# more than two solution of given equality and inequality

Tags: inequality, logarithms

The number of ordered pair (x,y) satisfying 4{log x}^2 + 1 = 2{log y} and log (x)^2 >= log y .Here the base of logarithm is 2.
I solved the question but then i realized that i get two different answer with these 2 inequalities in order which i use first to approach but the book says it has only one solution(but none of my 2 solution matches it).e.g.:- i let (log x)=a and (log y)=b and i used the inequality to find the value of b and used that value of b in the equality to find a, and my final solution was y=2 and x=√2,(1/√2) ; and then i used inequality to find the value of a and used that value of in given equality to find value of b and From here my final answer was x=√2 and y=2. I would like to know if my method is correct and it has more than one solution or not. Also the given solution in book of this problem is x=√2 and y€(0,2]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

Thus, $$4\log_2^2x+1\leq2\log_2x^2$$ or
$$4\log_2^2x+1\leq4\log_2|x|.$$ 
Since the domain here is $x>0$, we obtain 
$$(2\log_2x-1)^2\leq0$$ or $$\log_2x=\frac{1}{2}$$ and $$x=\sqrt2.$$
Thus, $\log_2y=1$, which gives $y=2$ and we got the unique solution
$$\left(\sqrt2,2\right).$$
Id est, the answer is $1$.

Comment: i think u didn't understand what i was asking.

Comment: @user496593 I fixed. See now. Maybe do you mean that $\left\{\log_2y\right\}$ is a fractional part of $\log_2y$?

Comment: i get two different answer with these 2 inequalities in order which i use first to approach. i let (log x)=a and (log y)=b and i used the inequality to find the value of b and used that value of b in the equality to find a, and my final solution was y=2 and x=√2,(1/√2) ; and then i used inequality to find the value of a and used that value of in given equality to find value of b and From here my final answer was x=√2 and y=2 . i get it that u used tge second method to find but what about the first one. is it wrong? and if yes why so

Comment: @user496593 After your substitutions we obtain: $4a^2+1=2b$ and $2a\geq b$, which gives $4a^2+1\leq4a$ or $a=\frac{1}{2}$, which just ends the solution because we get $b=1$ only.